# How to delete keyboard text replacements on macOS 10.15 that won't stay deleted

Tags: macos, keyboard, icloud

I have several text replacements in the `System Preferences -> Keyboard -> Text Tab` that will not stay deleted.  I can delete them and they re-appear within 3 seconds. They also cannot be renamed successfully as any attempt to rename them causes their name to change back.

I have tried deleting all text replacements from all devices, it does not work.

When I turn off internet access and delete the text replacements, they stay deleted until my Mac gets internet access again.  If I disable the main iCloud account, the text replacements stay deleted until I re-enable the iCloud account.

This is causing text replacements to frequently not work and frequently not synchronize between my devices.

Comment: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7228780 will this help ?

Comment: I found the text replacements within macOS just to limited.  I spent the $5 USD for [aText](https://trankynam.com/atext/) text expander and I haven't been disappointed.  There's a 3 week trial to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Sounds good but I need something that seamlessly mirrors between all of my devices, Mac, iPads, iPhones, iPod Touches (note the "s" on the end of each).